# Numpy Array for SVM model rather than a DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, svm

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read the data.
data = np.asarray(pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None))
# Assign the features to the variable X, and the labels to the variable y. 
X = data[:,0:2]
y = data[:,2]

# TODO: Create the model and assign it to the variable model.
# Find the right parameters for this model to achieve 100% accuracy on the dataset.
model = SVC()
model.fit(X,y)
```

2 Questions:

1. the data goes into a numpy array from a pandas Dataframe (by pd.read_csv).
   Is that better? Is there a good reason for that? why not stay with the DataFrame?
2. I do not understand this notation:
   X = data[:,0:2]
   y = data[:,2]
   What does it do?

Thank you.

The data consists of a CSV file with many rows like this:
0.28917,0.65643,0
It includes three columns, the first 2 comprising of the coordinates of the points, and the third one of the label.

Comment: `X = data[:,0:2]` means take all rows, and take columns 0 to 2 exclusive. So, take columns 0 and 1 and assign them to `X`. `y = data[:,2]` means take the entire column 2 and assign it to `y`. You simply assign different parts of your data to variables, so thatt you don't have to repeat complicated expression like `model.fit(data[:,0:2], data[:,2])`

Comment: I see. Thank you !

Comment: For a more detailed explanation of indexing in numpy, check [this link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: thanks for sharing